# Xpath wrong in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver           
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import requests
from csv import writer


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) 

time.sleep(2)
url='https://app.vidiq.com/auth/login'

driver.get(url)

email=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#email")
email.send_keys("----------")

password=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#password")
password.send_keys("-------")

time.sleep(2)
login=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']")
login.click()

time.sleep(30)


element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='research-link']//span")))
element.click()
```

I want to click on the `keyword`  but they will not click on it Kindly suggest to me what I am doing wrong here then the program will end so is there issue in my xpath

This is the XPath I made for `keyword`  so is there my xpath are correct

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='research-link']//span")))element.click()
element.click()
```

Error they show me

```
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

[4232:16160:0310/163027.484:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the `tbsCertificate` error, add the below line: This will ignore those errors.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

Coming to your next issue, which is trying to locate the "Keywords" element. Try this Xpath expression:

```
(//div[@id='research-link']//span)[1]
```

Code should be:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='research-link']//span)[1]")))
element.click()
```

Or:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='research-link']//span)[1]")))
element.click()
```

You can even try using below XPath expression:
This expression searches all the `span` nodes which contain text "Keywords"

```
//span[text()='Keywords']
```

Comment: they show these error 
`[7284:15376:0310/162526.324:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate`

Comment: This error has nothing to do with finding the desired element. Can you update your question with full error stack trace?

Comment: I have add full error in my question

Comment: Check the updated answer. Add this code `options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])`. Let me know the status.

Comment: I add these lines but the same error shows me again...........

Comment: Thanks the error is solve now

Comment: You are welcome. Upvote and accept the answer if this has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the `Keyword` element, Use either of the `xpath`

1.

```
//div[@id='research-link']//span[text()='Keywords']
```

or
2.

```
//a[.//span[text()='Keywords']]
```