# Selenium Issue : ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I don't really code, but I try to automate some tasks. I encountered an issue that I cannot solve. I have been trying for several days.
My code :

```
# Remplissage des champs
    nom_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="edit-nom"]')))
    nom_input.send_keys(NOM)
    email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="edit-from"]')))
    email_input.send_keys(ADRESSE_EMAIL)
    objet_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="edit-objet"]')))
    objet_input.send_keys(OBJET)
    message_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="edit-message"]')))
    message_input.send_keys(MESSAGE)

    # Envoi du formulaire
    send_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="edit-submit"]') # on stocke l'élément dans une variable
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", send_button)
```

The issues :

> Erreur : DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58097/devtools/browser/e9db2647-35d2-4b97-87fc-5a57f7e3146b
> [22280:10456:0312/223717.960:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
> ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
> ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

> [22280:24956:0312/223718.741:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
> ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
> ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

I tried using all the find_element methods such as xpath, id, etc... I see the form being filled out when I used xpath but when its sending time I encounter this problem. (resolved)

And for the first one, I don't know what the problem is. Could you help me ?

Comment: can you plz share how you resolved it ?

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_css_selector` is deprecated.

Please use `find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `tbsCertificate` error, below line of code will ignore those errors.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75695484/7598774